# How do I forward all requests from local port to port on my remote Amazon EC2 instance which is using a custom ssh port

Tags: ssh, aws, amazon-ec2

I am trying to forward all requests from local port 8888 to port 8888 to my remote Amazon EC2 instance. The only difference is that my EC2 instance is running ssh on custom port 56129.

I can successfully ping my ec2 instance from the local system but when I try to forward requests from a local port to a port on ec2 instance, I am getting:

> channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

I am using the following command:

```
ssh -i <pem key> -NfL 8888:localhost:8888 <user>@<instance ip> -p 56129
```

Then it asks for a password. There are no messages when it accepts the password. But as soon as I open localhost:8888 in my browser, I get the error message:

> channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Some observations -

- Running `ssh -i <pem key> <user>@<instance ip> -p 56129` with a
  password is successful.
- I am running Jupyter Notebook at port 8888 in EC2 instance. curl localhost:8888 returns nothing when done after ssh-ing into the instance

Comment: the message tells "channel 2: administratively prohibited: open failed" and not "channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused". That means the **remote** sshd server doesn't allow this in its settings. Look at the remote sshd configuration and logs.

Comment: What would you like me to see?

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the local address to achieve what you want:

```
ssh -i <pem key> -NfL localhost:8888:localhost:8888 <user>@<instance ip> -p 56129
```

or

```
ssh -i <pem key> -NfL localhost:8888:<instanceip>:56129 <user>@<instance ip>
```

As it's not 100% clear what you want to achieve.

Test with

```
telnet ipaddress portnumber
```

Which gives you a connect (or not) in advance and when running it to check.

Comment: I am trying to connect to the application running in the remote server from my local system. Does this help you?

Comment: The second option isn't making sense. Application is running on port 8888 in the remote server. Why would I want to connect to 56129 port?

Answer (score 0):

The message tells the (remote) `sshd` server settings doesn't allow to forward TCP ports.

This option should be enabled on the remote `sshd` server's configuration (usually in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

> [`AllowTcpForwarding`](https://manpages.debian.org/sshd_config.5#AllowTcpForwarding)
>
> Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted. The available options
> are `yes` (the default) or `all` to allow TCP forwarding, `no` to prevent
> all TCP forwarding, `local` to allow local (from the perspective of
> ssh(1)) forwarding only or `remote` to allow remote forwarding only.
> Note that disabling TCP forwarding does not improve security unless
> users are also denied shell access, as they can always install their
> own forwarders.

The default above is for a Debian system and might not be the default on AWS' `sshd`. This option has to be set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as `yes`/`all` or at least `local` to enable the port forwarding:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

and the remote `sshd` server should be reloaded or restarted for the option to take effect on *new* connections. Be careful, any syntax error might prevent further access if not quickly corrected on a connection still in use.

There are many other subtleties related to enabling port forwarding. For example a dedicated entry in user's [`authorized_keys`](https://manpages.debian.org/authorized_keys.5#permitopen=_host:port_) could restrict it to specific ports only (as long as the system-wide configuration still allows it).

Comment: I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname 8888:localhost:8888: Name or service not known` when I set `AllowTcpForwarding` to `yes` or comment it out

Comment: You'll have to give again the exact command that was used: probably a typo. It doesn't look like the previous command done in your question.